# Error in Insert query in a table by executing one system proc in sybase

Tags: sap-ase

I am getting error while inserting data inside table TableSizes with below query,
Could anyone please help me in this regard.

```
declare @name varchar(256)
select @name ='TestTable'
begin
insert into workdb..TableSizes
exec sp_spaceused @name
end
go
Msg 156, Level 15, State 2
Server '<ServerName>', Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, try running without any variables..`insert into workdb..TableSizes     exec sp_spaceused TestTable`  Since that does not work, I would question whether you can pass the output of a system stored procedure that way.

Answer (score 0):

So what  you are trying to do here is to insert a proc result set into a table, which is not allowed unless the table is a proxy table.  If not, then complete the insert statement.